# MQTT connection Timeout in some client browsers

Tags: node.js, websocket, mqtt

```
 var myhost="some ip";
 var myport="80";
 var websocketclient = {
    'client': null,
    'connect': function () 
    {         
        var host =myhost;
        var port = myport;                                
        clientId = 'clientId-' + randomString(10);
        var keepAlive = 60;
        this.client = new Messaging.Client(host,port, clientId);
        this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
        this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;

        var options = {
                timeout: 30,                       //seconds
                keepAliveInterval: keepAlive,
                onSuccess: this.onConnect,
                onFailure: this.onFail                   
        };
        if (username.length > 0 && password.length > 0){
            options.userName = username;
            options.password = password;
            this.client.connect(options); 
        }

    }};
```

In some clients browsers mqtt is not connecting. websocket connection is connected.
I'm Using hivemq mqttws31.js file. Please help me.

Comment: Some information about which browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome...) would probably be helpful here. Also show keepAlive be longer than the timeout value?

Comment: Not connecting in all browsers(IE,Firefox,Chrome).

Comment: Can you paste more of the code? Do you actually call the connect method? Do you see something in the browser development console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Change Your port number other than 80 so every user will connect from any browser and no anti virus will block the port.

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed this issue. Actual problem is with client avast anti virus. Avast is blocking 80 port.After unblocking 80 port its working.